# Dynamic Linq in Entity Framework Core

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, linq-expressions, dynamic-linq

I need to create a Linq query having **Where** and **Select** both dynamic.I am searching something like below code which will work in .net core.

```
var result = myQuery
.Where("Field1=\"SomeValue\" && Field2=\"SomeValue\"")
.Select("new (Field1, Field2, Field3)");
```

I tried above one by adding **System.Linq.Dynamic** for .net core but both **Where** and **Select** is not supporting dynamic string values.Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: What is the problem? In string concatennation?

Comment: [Dynamic LINQ](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) is definitely the right solution. Please add more details on what is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure to use [NuGet : System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/).
2. And make sure you include the correct namespace:

   ```cs
   using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;
   ```
3. And make sure your `myQuery` is an `IQueryable<T>`

---

With this it should be able to use your code like:

[image: example]

Comment: I was using System.Linq.Dynamic instead of System.Linq.Dynamic.Core that was the issue, thanks for the help